# Convert .3DS or .OBJ files to .MD2

Tags: augmented-reality

I am using Metaio's Creator to create an AR event and using a model the client purchased from TurboSquid.com. Everytime I try to convert the .3DS file to an .MD2 file I get an error that there are to many polygons.

Is there a program that can automatically convert the .3DS or .OBJ to an .MD2 without lowering the polygon count or automatically taking polygons out without risking the integrity of the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the model has too many polygons you can import it into a 3DCC-tool like Max, Maya or Blender and use their tools to reduce the polygon-count.
For example using Blender 2.49 you can use the PolyReducer-Script, that preserves UV-Coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

`MD2` only supports 4096 polygons inherently. As @0r10n said, you have to reduce the number of polygons to make it working with `MD2`. For conversion, I had the best experience using the `QTip` plugin for 3Ds Max here: http://qtipplugin.com/

Very easy to use and very powerful.